# valid children of XmlNode according to DTD?

Tags: c#, xml, dtd

consider this:

I'm inside a (selfbuilt) XML Editor and am about to add a Child to an XmlNode.
**How do I know which types of children are valid according to a DTD.**

it's a behaviour like Intellisense.
I couldn't find any .NET classes for "parsing" the DTD.

How would i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the DOM Level 1 Core standard which `XmlDocument` implements does not provide any access to `<!ELEMENT>` and `<!ATTLIST>` declarations in a DTD (internal subset or, if configured to read it, external DTD).

You do get `Document.DocumentType.Entities`, which tells you what general entities (`&something;`) were defined in the DTD, and `Notations`, which is largely useless, but not `Elements` or `Attlists`. Whilst there exist DOMs that will retain this information, I'm not aware of any for .NET (unless you want to go running pxdom through IronPython, which would probably be a bit of a pain and not at all fast) and nothing that integrates with `System.Xml`.

You could possibly hook up [saxdotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxdotnet/), using a [declHandler](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ext/DeclHandler.html) (looks like eg. ExpatReader.SetDeclHandlerForParsing in saxdotnet) to pick up these declarations. Either as a separate parse process for the internalSubset/systemId DTD, or as a replacement for .NET's own parsing, converting the event stream in an XmlDocument manually.

Comment: yeah I noticed Document.DocumentType, which wasn't of any help. this seems strange though. How is XmlReader validating against the DTD? haven't had any time yet to start up Reflector to see...

Comment: Don't know but it doesn't seem to be part of the publically-available API. (It's quite common for XML parsers to not provide access to the DTD declarations, unfortunately.)

Comment: i'm going for xsd! seems better and .net does actually support what i want!

Comment: Yeah, DTD is a pretty old-and-nasty method of validation... if you can migrate to one of the more modern schema languages that's definitely preferable.